# Broadcom NetXtreme II GigE Teaming Does Not Use Unique MAC, Causing Collisions

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, arp, bonding, mac-address

I currently have a new Dell server on my local (inside) network that I have setup to use three of the four nics to create a team.  Examples below.

```
NIC_1 - mac: 000000000001 - ip: n/a
NIC_2 - mac: 000000000002 - ip: 10.99.1.102
NIC_3 - mac: 000000000003 - ip: 10.99.1.103
NIC_4 - mac: 000000000004 - ip: 10.99.1.104

SUPERFASTNIC - mac: 000000000002 - ip: 10.99.1.105
```

Currently I'm using nics 2-4 to create the team.  The issue is when the team gets created (SuperFastNic) it has a mac address of NIC_2, NIC_3, or NIC_4 and NOT it's own unique mac address.  This causes issues on my router's side and makes it throw warnings due to the fact that 2 different IP addresses have the same mac.  My ASA5505 keeps showing the following warning...

```
Received ARP request collision from 10.99.1.105/0000.0000.0002 on interface inside with existing ARP entry 10.99.1.105/0000.0000.0003
```

I have tried to force the team's mac address assignment by setting the following registry entry, but I think this will only work if the entry is a mac address that belongs to one of the physical adaptors... :/

```
\HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Blfp\Parameters\1\TeamMacAddress
```

Any ideas on how I can get my team's mac address to be different from the physical nics?

Comment: What operating system? What tool(s) are you using to create the team?

Comment: There is **no** problem with multiple IP addresses having the same MAC address, and I find it highly unlikely that it's the root cause.

Comment: Why are you trying to assign individual IP addresses to interfaces that are part of a team? Either the individual interfaces should be IP devices or the team interface should be, but not both.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Good spot! I presumed he was assigning multiple IP's to the bonded interface.

Comment: Pauska: The OS is Windows 2008 Server Standard.  I'm using the Broadcom NetXtreme II GigE software called "Broadcom Advanced Control Suite 4" to create the team.  David: I thought each nic would always have it's own IP address.  Should there not be an ip address for each nic?  Just one single IP for the entire team?  The software tells me to give an IP for each NIC in the team...  That's why I did it in the first place.

I think the reason for each nic having it's own IP is used for LiveLink IPv4.  To check if there is a connection on each nic.  Should I turn off LiveLink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason each NIC needed an IP in the team was due to the LiveLink IPv4 support.  Each individual IP was used to ping other targets to see if the link was actually up and live.